# How to properly initialize a big structure with doubly linked list?

Tags: c, data-structures, initialization, doubly-linked-list

I am practicing linked lists by attempting to make a simple school structure, I keep error checking as I go and noticed this:

```
$ gcc list.c -Wall
list.c: In function ‘newStudent’:
list.c:52:15: warning: variable ‘newNode’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  studentList *newNode;
               ^~~~~~~
list.c: In function ‘initLists’:
list.c:36:14: warning: ‘auxSt’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  auxSt->name = NULL;
              ^
list.c:41:14: warning: ‘auxR’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  auxR->names = NULL;
              ^
list.c:46:16: warning: ‘school’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  school->rooms = NULL;
                ^
```

This is my code so far...

```
typedef struct roomList roomList;
typedef struct school school;
typedef struct studentList studentList;

struct studentList
{

    char *name;
    int  grade;
    studentList *next;
    studentList *prev;
};

struct roomList
{   
    int class;
    int nrOfStudents;
    studentList *names;
    roomList *next;
    roomList *prev; 
};

struct school
{
    int totalStudents;
    roomList *rooms;
};

void initLists()
{
    studentList *auxSt;
    auxSt->name = NULL;
    auxSt->next = auxSt->prev = NULL;
    auxSt = NULL;

    roomList *auxR;
    auxR->names = NULL;
    auxR->next = auxR->prev = NULL;
    auxR = NULL;

    school *school;
    school->rooms = NULL;
    school = NULL;
}


int main()
{
    initLists();

     return 0;
}
```

But it appears that after I initialize my aux variables first with `NULL` before going to the members this warning disappears. But I have concerns over initializing the aux variables with NULL before its own members. 
Am I on the right path for this?

**What is the advantage of using an `init()`function over initializing as you're inserting? Haven't seen almost a single example online with this function.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look at the first function.

```
studentList *newStudent(int class, char *name)
{
    studentList *newNode;
    newNode = (studentList*)malloc(sizeof(studentList));

    return NULL;     
}
```

You are not returning anything. Well, you return NULL pointer. The whole function is equivalent to

```
studentList *newStudent(int class, char *name)
{
    return NULL;     
}
```

with the only exception that your code causes an extra memory leak. You need to replace `return NULL` with `return newNode`. Also, never cast malloc and use the var instead of type as arg for sizeof. Just use `newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode))`

The function `initLists` has similar problems. You create a couple of variables, but you don't use them in a way that matters after the function is done. You also try to dereference unallocated pointers.

> Am I on the right path for this?

Not really. I would suggest studying pointers and memory allocation a bit more, and search for example code for doubly linked lists.

Comment: I probably shouldn't have included the other functions then, ```return NULL;``` is a placeholder.

Comment: How do I do it correctly? From what I understand about linked lists, I should create aux variables to access members right? There are pointers that need to initialized in them. Is this not the way?

Comment: @RamiRaghfan absolutely not, you need to read your lecture notes and/or read the chapters dealing with pointers and linked listes in your C text book.

Answer (score 0):

```
studentList *auxSt;  // auxSt is not initialized
auxSt->name = NULL;  // here you dereference a non initialized pointer
```

Of course you get `‘auxSt’ is used uninitialized in this function` warning here, what do you expect?

Now I guess you tried this:

```
studentList *auxSt = NULL;  // auxSt is initialized to NULL
auxSt->name = NULL;         // here you dereference an initialized pointer (no warning)
```

Here you don't get a `‘auxSt’ is used uninitialized in this function` warning, because here `auxSt` *is* initialized. However this code is still wrong because dereferencing a NULL pointer isn't going to end well.

So globally you're probably not on the right path here.

The whole `initLists` function is totally wrong.

Comment: I see... so If I used a value other than NULL to initialize would this code work? something ```school->nil;```. but what should I do or where do I look to make it work with NULL?

Comment: Google "linked list C", there are tons of examples, tutorials, explanations etc.

Comment: I don't believe I've ever came across an example with 3 doubly linked lists within each other and a structure that that contains all. It also appears that an init() function is unnecessary?

Comment: Start writing code for one single linked list. If you're able to do this, you're also able to write code for a linked list containing another linked list etc.